# jquery validation HTML tag for number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

How can I create a numeric HTML attribute to use on my form properties? The attribute needs to be validated with JQuery Validation.

The number from that field needs to be an integer.

If it already exists, how can I use it?

If not, I can use some already existent implementations. But I'm pretty sure there has to be one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

When I tried to use it, I tried as this code says:

```
<input type="text" number/>
```

The problem is that the number attribute must have a value and it must be set to true:

```
<input type="text" number="true"/>
```

Now it works.

Comment: You could also use input type="number" =)

Comment: Attribute `number` is not valid, it should be `type="number"`

Comment: As already stated, [`number` is not a valid `input` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). And you **must** have a unique `name` attribute for the jQuery Validate plugin to work properly.